# How do you format arrays to hold objects?

Tags: java, arrays, object

Im new to java and I am super confused on how you format arrays to hold objects, specifically with multiple data types. I am trying to make an array called myMonsters that essentially holds a bunch of other monsters, which is a string and an integer. 1, I really don't understand how to put objects into an array. 2, I don't get why the array are under one class name instead of another.
What I mean -->

```
private Monster[] myMonsters;
    private int s;
    public Monsters(int size)
    {
        s = size;
        myMonsters = new Monster[s];
    }
    public void add(int spot, Monsters m)
    {
        myMonsters[spot] = m;
    }
```

This creates the array that holds the monster objects. I don't understand why I would create the array under Monster. Doesn't it make more sense to create it under the Monsters class, where the monster objects are being held?

```
private int weight;
    private int height;
    private int age;
    public Monster( int a, int h, int w )
    {
        age = a;
        height = h;
        weight = w;
    }
```

And of course this creates the objects.
I can tell how poorly formatted this questions is but can you still help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "create the array _under_ Monster"? The array is in the `Monsters` class, from I can see.

Comment: *"Doesn't it make more sense to create it under the Monsters class, where the monster objects are being held?"* .... how would that make more sense? Why would a single monster "know" a bunch of other monsters and store it in its array?

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but it is usually easier to use ArrayLists than arrays.

Comment: Is this your code? or you are analyzing someone else's?

Answer (score 1):

A class is a template, like a [cookie-cutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie_cutter) for making cookies. A class has no content, just as a cookie-cutter has no cookie dough.

A cookie-cutter exists only to make delicious cookies. A class exists only to make useful objects (a.k.a. instances). Objects have content inside, just as cookies have dough inside.

`Monster` is the class, the cookie-cutter, for making various monster objects.

In Java 16 and later, we can more briefly define a class as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395). The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```java
package work.basil.example.animalkingdom.cookies;

public record Monster(String name , int weight)
{
}
```

As a conventional class, that would be:

```java
package work.basil.example.animalkingdom.cookies;

import java.util.Objects;

public final class Monster
{
    private final String name;
    private final int weight;

    public Monster ( String name , int weight )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String name ( ) { return name; }

    public int weight ( ) { return weight; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object obj )
    {
        if ( obj == this ) return true;
        if ( obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass() ) return false;
        var that = ( Monster ) obj;
        return Objects.equals( this.name , that.name ) &&
                this.weight == that.weight;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( name , weight );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Monster[" +
                "name=" + name + ", " +
                "weight=" + weight + ']';
    }
}
```

Let's cut some cookies using that cookie-cutter. We want to represent 3 monsters, each with a different name and different weight.

```java
Monster x = new Monster( "Alice" , 42 );
Monster y = new Monster( "Bob" , 77 );
Monster z = new Monster( "Carol" , 58 );
```

There we have three separate objects, each cut from the same `Monster` class. We are currently handling the 3 monsters separately, each assigned to separate variables.

If we want to track those monsters together, in a particular order, we do not need your `Monsters` class. Just use an array.

Say we want them organized together by weight.

```java
Monster[] monstersByWeight = new Monster[ 3 ];
monstersByWeight[ 0 ] = x;
monstersByWeight[ 1 ] = z;
monstersByWeight[ 2 ] = y;
```

The `Monster[]` says we want this variable named `monstersByWeight` to hold an array that holds `Monster` objects. The `new Monster[ 3 ]` creates such an array, an array with three empty slots. The `=` puts that array of three empty slots into the variable named `monstersByWeight` so we can use it later.

Dump that array to the console, to inspect.

```java
String output = Arrays.toString( monstersByWeight );
System.out.println( "output = " + output );
```

> output = [Monster[name=Alice, weight=42], Monster[name=Carol, weight=58], Monster[name=Bob, weight=77]]

You said:

> … to hold objects, specifically with multiple data types

There is **only *one* data type** involved here: `Monster`. We have only `Monster` objects to track. So the data type of the array named `monstersByWeight` is `Monster`.

If we want to add another `Monster` object:

```
Monster david = new Monster( "David" , 63 ) ;
```

…to our array, we need to open up a slot. Using arrays, this is tedious programming. Likely we would create another array, move elements from old array to new array while skipping the slot we want to keep open for our new `Monster`. Not fun writing that code.

Fortunately, that code has already been written. We can use the class `ArrayList`. This class implementing the `List` interface. `ArrayList` can do all the element-insertion work for us.

```java
List< Monster > monstersByWeight = new ArrayList<>() ;
```

The `List< Monster > monstersByWeight` says we want a list that holds `Monster` objects. The `new ArrayList<>()` instantiates such a list, of a default size.

Next we add our `Monster` objects.

```java
monstersByWeight.add( x ) ;
monstersByWeight.add( z ) ;
monstersByWeight.add( y ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( monstersByWeight ) ;
```

> [Monster[name=Alice, weight=42], Monster[name=Carol, weight=58], Monster[name=Bob, weight=77]]

Later we can insert our new `Monster` object named `David`, assigned to variable named `david`. At weight of 63, this new monster belongs before the one named `Bob` but after the one named `Carol`. Like arrays, the `List` interface uses annoying zero-based counting rather than ordinal counting. To specify the 3rd element, we say `2` (annoying, as I said).

```java
monstersByWeight.add( 2 , david ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( monstersByWeight ) ;
```

> [Monster[name=Alice, weight=42], Monster[name=Carol, weight=58], Monster[name=David, weight=63], Monster[name=Bob, weight=77]]

You asked:

> This creates the array that holds the monster objects. I don't understand why I would create the array under Monster. Doesn't it make more sense to create it under the Monsters class, where the monster objects are being held?

No, you would *not* want a collection of `Monster` objects stored within the class of `Monster`. The job of the `Monster` class is to define the state (data) and behavior (methods) for any one `Monster` object (instance) that represents any one real-world monster.

You want a separate class to track a bunch of `Monster` objects together. Here in this Answer we used an instance of the `ArrayList` class which we named `monstersByWeight` to track our group of monsters. You could just as well have written your own `MonsterList` class if you wanted to do all that array-rearranging yourself, as practice. But for real work, use `ArrayList`.

The principal at work here is called [*separation of concerns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). The `ArrayList` class knows nothing of what it means to be a `Monster`. And the `Monster` class knows nothing of how to group together `Monster` objects. Following this principal leads to clean, well-organized code that is easier to read, comprehend, and maintain.